# Xcode tintedImageProvider for Apple Watch complication rectangularTemplate.imageProvider

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

Im having an issue I've been trying to solve on my own for ages with no luck.
Im using the Apple documentation and the video here [Exploring Tinted Graphic Complications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/253/)
I created a graphic from code that produces a png from data that fits into the square on the Apple Watch face. In the ComplicationController.swift file I have this code

```
graphicRectangularImage = UIImage(cgImage: context.makeImage()!, scale: 2.0, orientation: .up)
...
rectangularTemplate.imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: graphicRectangularImage)
```

and set the privacy of the complications to `handler(.hideOnLockScreen)`.

And that works great to create a full colour image. And it hides when locked.

[image: Mulitcolour locked and unlocked]

[image: Monochrome locked and unlocked]

So when the users has a multicolour face that's fine.
But if I add a twopeiceimage like this

```
graphicRectangularImage = UIImage(cgImage: context.makeImage()!, scale: 2.0, orientation: .up) 
twoPieceImageBackground = UIImage(cgImage: context.makeImage()!, scale: 2.0, orientation: .up) 
twoPieceImageForeground = UIImage(cgImage: context.makeImage()!, scale: 2.0, orientation: .up)  

let tintedImageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: graphicRectangularImage, twoPieceImageBackground: twoPieceImageBackground, twoPieceImageForeground: twoPieceImageForeground)  

rectangularTemplate.imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: graphicRectangularImage, tintedImageProvider: tintedImageProvider)
```

The foreground image is just the bar and the words "Past 7 days:" as those are the only two bits I want to be in yellow.
The background is the rest of the image, so that can be grey.
It works great on the multicolour screen but when using the tinted image provider the image does not hide when locked.

[image: Tinted image provider locked and unlocked]

Image does not hide when locked. But it does behave correctly if you change back to multicolour, that's the weird bit.

The locked image appears to come from the image file I put into the Assets folder for the complication under the section for the complications, but there is not a space for me to add a locked image for the two-peice image, so its just using what was already there, except for the app name, that changes when locked.

[image: Xcode image slots]

Please help point me in the right direction so the tinted foreground image hides when Apple Watch is locked.

Comment: I used my free code support token with my developer account and spoke to a member of the Apple Developer Technical Support team and he was able to re-create the issue and advised me to file a bug report FB7742362